# Erlang: doing a good job

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, coding-style

I've done a bit of functional programming, and I have a couple online references, so I'm finding basic Erlang programming pretty easy.

But since I've done far more procedural/object-oriented programming than functional programming, I expect my Erlang code isn't very well styled or efficient.

Can anybody recommend any resources that cover good, efficient, well-styled functional programming?

thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely try and get your hands on the erlang book:
http://www.pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang/programming-erlang

The first section of the book is available free online and would make an excellent companion when you are just learning the language:
http://erlang.org/download/erlang-book-part1.pdf

If you are looking for something more advanced, or wanting to learn tips and tricks about the language/OTP then I would recommend "Erlang in practice" screencasts:
http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-kserl/erlang-in-practice
Although they are $40, they are high quality screencasts and I believe well worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about architecture and design as about programing strategy and about coding style as about tactics than good sources are:

- **strategy** - [Making reliable systems in the presence of software errors](http://www.sics.se/~joe/thesis/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf)
- **tactics** - [Programming Rules and Conventions](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml)

I think main rules are:

- make short and readable functions
- keep number of parameters, tuple members, record parameters and other low (less than 5) - structure your data
- do and undo thinks in same function - make safe functions - avoid others to shoot themselves
- KISS - Keep It Simple and Stupid (Stupid doesn't mean Dumb but don't make over-smart)